# How do I concatenate values for array elements that share the same key in order to strip out duplicate keys?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional PHP array:

```
$arr = array(0 => array('www.foo.com' => 'a'), 1 => array('www.bar.com' => 'b'), 2 => array('www.foo.com' => 'c'));
```

How would I concatenate values which share the same key and then remove the duplicates so I am left with:

```
$arr = array(0 => array('www.foo.com' => 'a,c'), 1 => array('www.bar.com' => 'b'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in function that concatenates values in the manner which you have in your example.

`array_combine()` concatenates arrays.

You need a function that somewhat mimics that functionality, but instead of dropping the value of keys that already have a value you need to do string concatenation.

```
function array_concat(Array $array1array, Array $array2array) {
    foreach ($array2array as $key => $value) {
        $newval = "";
        if (isset($array1array[$key])) {
            $newval = $array1array[$key] . ",";
        }
        $array1array[$key] = $newval . $value;
    }
    return $array1array;
}
```

From there you would need to adapt the function to apply to multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You could loop through the array while using the array_keys function to get the key of any existing keys, once you've figured out how many you have you can edit the first instance of the array to have the multiple values and then unset the rest of the values.

array_keys: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

unset: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php